# Serial Port Communication, Data Acquisiton, and ZedGraph - Too many Y coordinates for one X coordinate

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a sensor that is giving me force readings through a serial port.  I type a command to the serial port and it will give me back 1 reading each time.  I use a timer to send the command every so often.

```
private void daqTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{


    giveCommand("W");


    timeCounter += timeBetweenSamples;



}
```

Once the command gets sent, the serial port's dataReceived event fires and that's where the force reading comes in as a string.  I convert the string to a double and put it into a List<> of doubles.  Basically I am trying to get the table of values set up so I can perform a real time graphing in ZedGraph.  Everytime new data has arrived, store it in the array list and then update the graph.

```
//graphing section from DataReceived event
if (graphFlag == 1)
{
    dataReading = Convert.ToDouble(data);


    x.Add(timeCounter / 1000);
    y.Add(dataReading);


    //remake the graph each time a new X Y pair arrives
    zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();

    spl1 = new PointPairList(x.ToArray(), y.ToArray());



    GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
    myCurve1 = myPane.AddCurve(curveTitle, spl1, Color.Orange, SymbolType.None);


    zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();

    zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();

    zedGraphControl1.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate { zedGraphControl1.Refresh(); }));



    numSamples++; }
```

I got it work, except for each time reading, there are many force readings but I only want 1 force reading per time reading.  My export to file method shows this (time then force):

```
//export the data to a text file
    private void exportToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save the test results to a text file";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(myStream);

            foreach(double xvalue in x)
            {
                foreach(double yvalue in y)
                {

                    st.WriteLine(xvalue.ToString() + "   " + yvalue.ToString());

                }

            }

            myStream.Close();
        }

    }
```

0   -8.11182
0   -7.953495
0   -7.953495
0   -7.939525
0   -7.939525
0   -7.948838
0   -7.981434
0   -7.981434
0   -7.865019
0   -7.865019
0   -7.883646
0   -7.883646
0   -8.041971
0   -8.037314
0   -8.037314
0   -7.841736
0   -7.841736
0.1   -7.874332
0.1   -7.986091
0.1   -7.986091
0.1   -7.934868
0.1   -7.832423
0.1   -7.832423
0.1   -7.832423
0.1   -7.902272
0.1   -7.902272
0.1   -8.023344
0.1   -7.897616
0.1   -7.897616
0.1   -7.869676
0.1   -7.869676

Can anyone help me on getting 1 force reading for 1 time reading?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @M.Babcock: good catch - in time for me to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the event for dataReceived.  I've never had it work out the way I wanted it too.

I would just send the command, wait (however long the delay in receiving a reply is set on the controller) then read from the port.

I do this by just doing a Thread.Sleep(40) (for instance on my project the answer comes back within 40ms).  Then read the answer.  The dataReceived event will fire even when all the data hasn't been received on the port.  I can't think of any of my serial port applications I've used where I've decided on using the DataReceived event.  I just write to the port then listen for a reply in a loop of some sort.

you might also want to use the .ReatTo("....") on the SerialPort class, if you know what the answer will come back as , for instance if your answers come back with [0.9997...] in that format, you'd do

```
port.ReadTo("]");
```

This will block on the thread until you get that character in the input buffer.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try without using dataReceived, Yeah ReadTo() is nice I just read up to a newline and then trim

Comment: If you think this helped solved the problem, select it as the answer.

Comment: Well i tried your suggestion and basically got rid of the dataReceived part and moved it into the timer instead.  I write the command, wait about 50ms and then read like you said.  It works, but it still doesnt solve my table of values problem.  I still get tons of force readings for 1 time reading.  I just want 1 for 1! :(